# chrome api - move tab out of window

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, tabs, window

Is it possible to take an existing tab, move it out of its window and create a new window directly?

Using the [window api](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows) I can create a new window with an empty tab, and with the [tab api](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs) I can move my tab of interest there and remove the empty tab. That's quite a lot of steps and the visual is very different from the manual action of dragging a tab out of its window.

Is there not a way to create a window directly from an existing tab with the api?

Comment: chrome.windows.create has `tabId` parameter exactly for this purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no possibility to do it in one way, just as you said.
First, you need to create a new empty window and then 
you can use [`chrome.tabs.move`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-move) method for it.

It has one limitation: `tabs can only be moved to and from normal (window.type === "normal") windows.`

Example:

```
chrome.tabs.move(tabId, { index : 1, windowId: 2 });
```

Comment: Damn that's very annoying!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this API appeared after your question, but it's now possible to move a tab to its own new window with the following command:

```js
chrome.windows.create({ tabId })
```

tabId: ["The ID of the tab to add to the new window."](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/windows/#property-create-createData-tabId)